# Can I put a Coroutines in while()?

Tags: python

I'm a programming novice, I need this architecture for some reason, but when I do, this method is not feasible, can someone provide some, alternative methods for me to learn? I want to run both asynchronous methods and generic methods

```
import json
import time
import random
import asyncio

async def post_data():
    Yaw=round(random.uniform(-1,1),2)
    print(Yaw)
    time.sleep(1)
asyncio.run(post_data)
        
def other_things():
    print("COOL")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
    
        post_data()
        other_things()
```

I have try this way, but the structure I really needed had to use asynchronous methods, so it didn't help me.

```
import json
import time
import random
import asyncio

def post_data():
    Yaw=round(random.uniform(-1,1),2)
    print(Yaw)
    time.sleep(1)
        
def other_things():
    print("COOL")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
    
        post_data()
        other_things()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
import json
import time
import random
import asyncio

async def post_data():
    Yaw=round(random.uniform(-1,1),2)
    print(Yaw)
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
        
def other_things():
    print("COOL")

async def main():
    while True:
        await post_data()
        other_things()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Result:

```
0.78
COOL
0.1
COOL
0.39
COOL
-0.9
...
```

Comment: It's really cool, thanks for the answer, I really benefited a lot